# Unable to render the Plaid Link UI from Plaid's CDN JS in my C# MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, cdn, plaid

I have been trying to load the Plaid Link UI in my MVC application. I referred this [codepen](https://codepen.io/alhertz/pen/MmpGXW) for the same.

I'm getting below error when I implemented the same code in my application.
[Plaid Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90klc.png)

As of now, I'm giving all the required info as hardcoded data in order to render the UI, and will add formatting subsequently once it is achieved.

Below is my Index.cshtml code:

```
@using System.Runtime.InteropServices
@using PlaidWebApplication.Helpers;



<form id="link-form-id" method="GET"></form>

<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"
        apiVersion="v2"
        data-form-id="link-form-id"
        data-key="<Here I pasted the secret key from my Plaid Account>"
        data-products="transactions"
        lang="en"
        isEmbedded="true"
        data-env="development"
       >
</script>
```

The above Codepen clearly gives the desired output, but for some reason I'm unable to replicate it at my end.

[Plaid Error at my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EmJm.png)
[Plaid CDN output from Codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHKhJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code sample above is not a currently supported method of embedding Link. In particular, the "data-key" field refers not to your secret, but to the public key, which is a key that has been deprecated and is not available to any new customers who signed up for Plaid after mid-2020.

The currently supported method of embedding Link is to use a Link token. You can learn more about initializing Link in the Link docs at https://plaid.com/docs/link/, or see the Plaid Tiny Quickstart (https://github.com/plaid/tiny-quickstart) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I did check the above implementation on Github. But unfortunately, couldn't recreate it in .NET. However, I did find a solution [here](https://github.com/anaya-upadhyay/Plaid-Integration). In case if anyone might need in future :)